# How can i unserialize an array and do insert query for each data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not used to work with arrays, and now i have to, and i need some help guys.

I have a list of absences,that contain multiples values. They are all ids (like `4,25,100...`) separed by a ','.

I want to add every single id in a table (insert query),i know the simple methode :

```
Insert into table (columns..) Values(values1,value2,...), 
(values1,value2,...),
(values1,value2,...),
(values1,value2,...)
```

But i dont know how to use it the the serialsed array.

Comment: You didn't show us the serialized array !

Comment: It's just Id's like (4,25,100).

I use an input to get the ids

Comment: what your php code looks like ?

Comment: $inserts = array();
        $inserts[]=$_POST['ids']; // $_POST['ids']=14,3,21;
        foreach ($insert as $username) {
       $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO absents VALUES ". implode(", ", $inserts);
}

Comment: I tried to make the comment as a code but it didn't work, i'm new to use this plateform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode the string on the commas, then iterate over the resulting array.  Understanding arrays is essential to PHP (and coding in general), so check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

```
$string = '4,25,100';
$array = explode(',', $string);
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`some_column`) VALUES ('".$v."')";
}
```

Comment: I'll try this tonight and then i'll be back here

Comment: It's seems to be working with a minor change ($value instead of $v).